# Onclick doesn't call a function

Tags: richfaces, onclick, ajax4jsf

While I am working with this code:

```
<rich:menuItem value="AND Search" onclick="addTagAND('#{tagElement.tag}')" id="and_search">
```

FUNCTION:

```
    <a4j:jsFunction name="addTagAND" 
actionListener="#{interfaceContainer.documentFormActions.addTagAND}" reRender="navigation, ..." 
ignoreDupResponses="true"  
data="#{searchResults.graphJSON}"  oncomplete="alert('AND');">  
<f:param name="tag" ></f:param>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

I don't get even the alert();
Is there any problem in the calling or any ideas??

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you surround it with form and session / keepAlive for the bean?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<rich:menuItem value="AND Search" onclick="alert('hi');" id="and_search">
```